# pip rust libc.so.6 error Centos

Tags: centos, python, pip, rust

OS: Centos 6

installed pip success

Installed Rust manually - success

```
curl https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
```

```
pip install cryptography 

     /root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc)
      /root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by /root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc)
      /root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_driver-a21dfa8672cc0cdd.so)
      /root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-05737cf45bd30456.so)
      /root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by /root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-05737cf45bd30456.so)
      /root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libLLVM-15-rust-1.65.0-stable.so)
      /root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by /root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libLLVM-15-rust-1.65.0-stable.so)
```

which led me to

Followed: this for the lib.so error
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50697155

also used it as a template for lib 2.17 and 2.15, reloaded the library paths as well

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/glibc-2.17/lib  #did the same 2.14 and 2.15

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/glibc-2.17/lib   #did the same 2.14 and 2.15
source /etc/environment   #did the same each time for 2.14 and 2.15 after i entered the above commands 

rustc
rustc: error while loading shared libraries: __vdso_time: invalid mode for dlopen(): Invalid argument
```

If I run yum I get the same command as above, but not if I open a new SSH session.

Once I open a new SSH session yum works without that error
but **rustc** command goes back to my initial error. Even though I reloaded the Env and library.

```
# rustc
/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc)
/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by /root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc)
/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_driver-a21dfa8672cc0cdd.so)
/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-05737cf45bd30456.so)
/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by /root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-05737cf45bd30456.so)
/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libLLVM-15-rust-1.65.0-stable.so)
/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by /root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libLLVM-15-rust-1.65.0-stable.so)
```

**env** output

```
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
HISTSIZE=10000
QTDIR=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3
QTINC=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/include
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
USER=root
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=01;36:*.au=01;36:*.flac=01;36:*.mid=01;36:*.midi=01;36:*.mka=01;36:*.mp3=01;36:*.mpc=01;36:*.ogg=01;36:*.ra=01;36:*.wav=01;36:*.axa=01;36:*.oga=01;36:*.spx=01;36:*.xspf=01;36:
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/root
PATH=/root/.cargo/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
PWD=/root
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root
QTLIB=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/lib
CVS_RSH=ssh
LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
G_BROKEN_FILENAMES=1
_=/bin/env
```

any tips?

Comment: Run `env` in both the faulty native session and in the SSH session and post the difference. It appears that your SSH session somehow has the right variables, so we could just note these down and export them into your session.

Comment: thank you i added the output in the question. i lost my session(s) from yesterday  i had to create a new one

Comment: Does the new session run binaries ok? If so, it appears that yes you have some faulty vars present on the native session. Try `env -i sh --noprofile` and int that shell run some of the binaries you have been trying to execute. If everything is okay and the binaries work in an empty environment, do `env` in the faulty session and locate and remove the discrepant variable definitions/exports. If all fails, try running `ldconfig` as root in a working session, that should clear and restore the linker cache.